# animateKeyframesWithDuration not persisting

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I am using `animateKeyframesWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:` which adjusts (moves) the frame of several views. However, when the animation completes the views revert to their original location - like the results of the animation are not persisting.

Here is the affected code:

```
UIView.animateKeyframesWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, options: .CalculationModeCubic, animations: {
            UIView.addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime(0.0, relativeDuration: 0.5) {

                //Moving main View
                tappedView.frame = CGRectMake((self.screenSize.width/2)-250, (self.screenSize.height/2)-250, 500, 500)

                //Centering other views
                tappedImage.frame = CGRectMake(185.5, 10, 129, 129)
                tappedTitle.frame = CGRectMake(100, 149, 300, 33)
                tappedShort.frame = CGRectMake(125, 175, 250, 85)
                tappedDetail.frame = CGRectMake(20, 230, 460, 135)
                tappedClose.frame = CGRectMake(370, 477, 128, 21)


            }
        }, completion:nil)
```

I have tried including a completion hander which sets the frame at their final location:

```
{(finished: Bool) -> Void in

            tappedImage.frame = CGRectMake(185.5, 10, 129, 129)
            tappedTitle.frame = CGRectMake(100, 149, 300, 33)
            tappedShort.frame = CGRectMake(125, 175, 250, 85)
            tappedDetail.frame = CGRectMake(20, 230, 460, 135)
            tappedClose.frame = CGRectMake(370, 477, 128, 21)

        }
```

which does work, but results in a flicker - like there is a slight delay between when the animation ends (and it starts reverting to the original location) and when the completion handler fires.

Any help appreciated.